# Does anyone still use Iometer?

Tags: windows, performance, benchmarking

Does anyone still use Iometer? It seems helpful, but I'm not sure if it's useful for the thing I am working on. I am trying create a benchmark computer performance test that can be run before and after a Windows Optimization program does its stuff (ex: PC Optimizer Pro or CCleaner). I want to be able to make a quick statement like *"CCleaner makes the computer run 50% faster"* or something along those lines.

> Iometer is an I/O subsystem measurement and characterization tool for single and clustered systems. It is used as a benchmark and troubleshooting tool and is easily configured to replicate the behaviour of many popular applications. ([Wikipedia source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iometer))

Are there any newer tools like this one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course! Iometer is still considered a very respected standard benchmark tool, and it is still used in [popular hardware reviews](http://hothardware.com/Articles/Four-Way-SSD-Round-Up-Redux-OCZ-Corsair-Kingston-Super-Talent/?page=5). If it provides all of the statistics you need, go for it!

If you're looking for newer tools, [SiSoft Sandra](http://www.benchmarkhq.ru/english.html?/sandradl_e.html) is very popular among the benchmarking crowd:

[image]